# IntelliJ IDEA - Spring Data JPA IDE support for Kotlin Repositories missing

Tags: intellij-idea

Hi I am using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2018.2.4, and i recently started writing my new Spring Data JPA repository classes in Kotlin language. I found that auto-suggest, entity highlighting in `@Query` methods, etc is not working when code is in Kotlin language. Is this a missing feature as of now or some problems with my setup?

Comment: Hey, did you get this working? I am facing the same issue!!

Comment: IntelliJ 2018.3.1 has this fixed. https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/img/2018.3/SpringJPA-1.png and this one https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/#v2018-3-spring--spring-boot

Answer (score 0):

Support for Kotlin based repositories has been added in Intellij Idea 2018.3.1

For more information, refer to this link:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/#v2018-3-spring--spring-boot